# NeoVim White background in 256 colors

Tags: vim, vi, kde-plasma, neovim

I'm somewhat new to Vim and NeoVim, so I installed the plugins and started up NeoVim and for some reason the 256 colors are not showing on NeoVim, instead I get this,

[image]

I'm using Konsole on KDE linux to run NeoVim and my NeoVim init file looks like this after loading the plugins before these lines,

```
syntax on

set encoding=utf8
set t_Co=256 "Explicitly tell vim that the terminal supports 256 colors"
colorscheme base16-solarized
```

My $TERM variable is xterm.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Someone is actually using Neovim. Is it stable ?

Comment: @rksh first, try running with `nvim --noplugin` to see if the problem goes away. This will tell you if it's a problem with your startup files (e.g. .vimrc). Then you can try to binary chop through your configuration to narrow down which part is causing the problem.

Comment: `$TERM` should be `xterm-256color`